# Ionic 3 DateTime - Show picker with current date when model is undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-directive, ionic3

I'm developing an application using Ionic 3 and I'm having a issue using [DateTime](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/) component. Supose I have a DateTime component in the user interface, and it is optional, so, the default value is optional. There is no min date and max date is 2 years from current date:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="dataInicial" doneText="Feito"
      cancelText="Cancelar" [max]="maxDate">
</ion-datetime>

export class AbaPedidosConfirmadosPage {

    dataInicial:Date;
    maxDate:string;

    constructor() {
        this.maxDate = moment().add(2, 'years').format('YYYY');
    }
}
```

So the question is: Is there a way the picker appears with current date selected when the model is undefined (or null)? This is for usability, in this case if the user needs select tomorrow date, it will need change the year, then the month and finally the day; if it loads the picker content in the current date, the user only need change the day.

I've tryied just create a directive to load the current date on click, but it was fired after the DateTime component proccess the event:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[load-date]'
})
export class LoadDateDirective {

    private lastValue:any;

    @Input() public ngModel:any;
    @Output('ngModelChange') modelChange:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    public constructor(private _elementRef:ElementRef,
                   private _renderer:Renderer) {

    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    _click(ev: UIEvent) {
        this.lastValue=this.ngModel;
        if(!this.lastValue) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopPropagation();
            this.modelChange.next(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I will try to explain it better. Here is the actual field, when the user clicks in the field, the picker shows the max date configured:

[image: Current date picker]

As I have no idea of which date user wants select, the desired behaviour would be the picker appearing with the current date, like this:

[image: Desired date picker]

As these fields are used to filter the results by date, they are optional, so the server returns everything if the dates are null.

Comment: Did you try..??

Comment: Yes, I tried... however it didn't work when I setted max attribute of ion-datetime. This max date should be a future date.

Comment: Just checked, its working. Updated plunker, have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official solution for this, but i have implemented a work around for your problem by invoking date picker programmatically.

Here is working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0KJ7xR?p=preview).

**HTML:**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary">Select Date</ion-label>
      <ion-input placeholder="Text Input" [value]="dataInicial | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'" (click)="open()"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item no-lines hidden="true">
      <ion-datetime #datePicker displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" (ionCancel)="this.dataInicial  = null" [(ngModel)]="dataInicial" doneText="Feito" cancelText="Cancelar" [max]="maxDate">
      </ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular'; 

@Component({
     selector: 'page-home',
     templateUrl: 'app/home.page.html'
 })
 export class HomePage {

     appName = 'Ionic App';
     dataInicial: Date;
     maxDate: string;

     constructor(public neavController: NavController) {}
     @ViewChild('datePicker') datePicker;
     open() {
         if (!this.dataInicial) {
             this.dataInicial = new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];
             setTimeout(() => {
                 this.datePicker.open();
             }, 50)
         } else {
             this.datePicker.open();
         }

     }
 }
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you say, "the model is undefined or null" I'm assuming that the variable "dataInicial" has not been defined.

If this is the case, then you should define it to the current date/time in your constructor... something like:

```
constructor() {
        this.maxDate = moment().add(2, 'years').format('YYYY');
        this.dataInicial = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD); 
        }
```

the datepicker for Ionic uses the ISO 8601 Datetime Format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmZ for its value, therefore, for the date you need to make it look like the string "2017-07-19"

Comment: The field is optional, so I need this behaviour when there is no value in model.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding about what you mean by optional. 
 I think, though, you mean that you want a value to be placed there... but not necessarily sent out with the rest of the form? If so, you might consider using an intermediate value. That is... use an ngModel variable to set the value that's on the screen, but only use it in the form it the field is .dirty, indicating that the user has actually selected the field. Then, you can pass that ngModel variable to the form that needs it.  However, I'm still not sure I understand.  Could you provide a little more information?